# How to reduce SQL queries in Django using prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to optimize a Django project (vers. 1.8.6) in which each page shows 100 companies and their data at once. I noticed that an unnecessary amount of SQL queries (especially with `contact.get_order_count`) are performed within the index.html snippet below:

index.html:

```
{% for company in company_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.get_order_count }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.get_order_sum|floatformat:2 }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="select{{company.pk}}" id=""></td>
    </tr>
    {% for contact in company.contacts.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>{{ contact.first_name }} {{ contact.last_name }}</td>
            <td>Orders: {{ contact.get_order_count }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem seems to lie in constant SQL queries to other tables using foreign keys. I looked up how to solve this and found out that `prefetch_related()` seems to be the solution. However, I keep getting a TemplateSyntaxError about being unable the parse the prefetch, no matter what parameter I use. What is the proper prefetch syntax, or is there any other way to optimize this that I missed?

I've included relevant snippets of model.py below in case it's relevant. I got `prefetch_related` to work in the defined methods, but it doesn't change the performance or query amount.

model.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def get_order_count(self):
        return self.orders.count()
    def get_order_sum(self):
        return self.orders.aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum']

class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, related_name="contacts", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    def get_order_count(self):
        return self.orders.count()

class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="orders")
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="orders")
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.order_number
```

EDIT:
The view is a ListView and defines the `company_list` as `model = Company`. I altered the view based on given suggestions:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company
    contacts = Contact.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('orders'))
    contact_list = Company.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('contacts', queryset=contacts))
    paginate_by = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `get_order_count` and `get_order_sum` methods causes one query every time the method is called. You can avoid this by [annotating the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
contacts = Contact.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('orders'), order_sum=Sum('orders'))
```

You then need to use a [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object to tell Django to use your annotated queryset.

```
contact_list = Company.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch("contacts", queryset=contacts)
```

Note that you need to add the `prefetch_related` to your queryset in the view, it is not possible to call it in the template.

Since you are using `ListView`, you should be overriding the `get_queryset` method, and calling `prefetch_related()` there:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = "mailer/index.html"
    model = Company
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Annotate the contacts with the order counts and sums
        contacts = Contact.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('orders')
        queryset = super(IndexView, self).get_queryset()
        # Annotate the companies with order_count and order_sum
        queryset = queryset.annotate(order_count=Count('orders'), order_sum=Sum('orders'))
        # Prefetch the related contacts. Use the annotated queryset from before
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('contacts', queryset=contacts))
        return queryset
```

Then in your template, you should use `{{ contact.order_count }}` instead of `{{ contact.get_order_count }}`, and `{{ company.order_count }}` instead of `{{ company.get_order_count }}`.

Comment: I tried adding the annotate and prefetch lines you gave into the view and replaced the line in index.html, but now the order counts don't appear at all. The view uses the ListView and `company_list` is presumably defined 
in it as `model = Company`, in case that affects 
anything.

Comment: I can't tell what you've tried from that comment. Please edit your question. If you're using `ListView`, then you should be overriding `get_queryset`.

Comment: I clarified what I added to the view in my original question, and I replaced `{{contact.get_order_count}}` with `{{contact.order_count}}` in index.html. I tried to look up on how to override `get_queryset`, so I assume I should do that in views.py?

Comment: You shouldn't add the queries to the class iteself, you need to move it into the `get_queryset` method. See the docs on [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) for more info.

Comment: I tried to override `get_queryset`, but I get a TypeError saying `get_queryset()` was given two arguments. It seems to complain about `super(IndexView, self)`.

Comment: It should be `super(IndexView, self).get_queryset()`.

Comment: It works now, and it drastically reduced the number of queries. I still want to optimize `{{ company.get_order_count }}` `{{ company.get_order_sum }}`, but I'll give it a try myself before asking for more advice. The solution should be similar to the one you gave, right?

Comment: Glad it worked. Yes, for `company.get_order_count` and `company.get_order_sum` you can use `annotate` again, but now you want to annotate the company queryset (`queryset` in the `get_queryset` method).

Comment: I tried annotating and prefetching the company queryset like the contact one. However, `{% for company in company_list %}` now gives a FieldError saying the `company` keyword can't be resolved to a field. It's likely the Company annotation clashes with the `company_list`, but I can't think of a way to solve this without rewriting the entire model.

Comment: You don't have to prefetch the companies. The queryset is already a queryset of companies. You just have to annotate the queryset with the order count and sum. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in views.py

```
company_list = Company.objects.all().prefetch_related("order", "contacts")
```